# What can I write between the .ajaxStart and .ajaxStop function to show a loading bar for say 3 seconds?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I want to show a loading gif on my site, but the loading process is so fast, that the loading bar shows for say 1/3 seconds and disapear, because the document is just uploading. How can I make when I want to show the loading gif for 3 seconds? What I should to write into the jquery code below?

jQuery code:

```
$(document).ajaxStart(function() {
 $("#loading").show();
 }).ajaxStop(function() {
 $("#loading").hide();
});
```

Have anyone of us an good idea?

Comment: You can use `delay` in a specific ajax call or `setTimeout` wrapping `hide()`.

Comment: @DontVoteMeDown's solution of wrapping the `hide` in a `setTimeout` will work for. However, I wonder is it bad UX to have a loading bar show even after the action itself is done? From a design standpoint, I see what you are going for but from a user's standpoint, it seems better UX to show your system is working and they can move onto their next action.

Comment: Okay, thank, it's work.